# $in slower when using indexed column

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to optimise my query and have found that when using *$in* on a non-indexed column that the performance appears to be faster than when on an indexed column.

For example:
I have added an index on *myCollection*: *{"entryVals.col1" : 1}*.

To confirm:
`db.myCollection.getIndexes()`
returns:

```
[
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "name" : "_id_",
                "ns" : "myDb.myCollection"
        },
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "key" : {
                        "entryVals.col1" : 1
                },
                "name" : "entryVals.col1_1",
                "ns" : "myDb.myCollection"
        } ]
```

I then run a count with a query (printing the time taken) on both the indexed and non-indexed columns.

**Count on indexed column**

```
var a = new Date().getTime();
db.myCollection.count({"entryVals.col1": {$in:["a","b","c","d"]}});
new Date().getTime() - a;
```

returns
`96` (time in ms)

**Count on non-indexed column**

```
var a = new Date().getTime();
db.myCollection.count({"entryVals.col2": {$in:["a","b","c","d"]}}); 
new Date().getTime() - a;
```

returns
`60` (time in ms)

Please bare in mind that I ran the queries several times and took an average (there were little to no anomalies) .

Is anyone able to help enlighten me as to why the query on the column that **is indexed** is slower please?

Thanks in advance.

---

**Explains**

**Count on indexed column**

`db.myCollection.explain().count({"entryVals.col1": {$in:["a","b","c","d"]}})
{
        "queryPlanner" : {
                "plannerVersion" : 1,
                "namespace" : "myDb.myCollection",
                "indexFilterSet" : false,
                "parsedQuery" : {
                        "entryVals.col1" : {
                                "$in" : [
                                        "a",
                                        "b",
                                        "c",
                                        "d"
                                ]
                        }
                },
                "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "COUNT",
                        "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "FETCH",
                                "inputStage" : {
                                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                        "keyPattern" : {
                                                "entryVals.col1" : 1
                                        },
                                        "indexName" : "entryVals.col1_1",
                                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                                        "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                                "entryVals.col1" : [ ]
                                        },
                                        "isUnique" : false,
                                        "isSparse" : false,
                                        "isPartial" : false,
                                        "indexVersion" : 2,
                                        "direction" : "forward",
                                        "indexBounds" : {
                                                "entryVals.col1" : [
                                                        "[\"a\", \"a\"]",
                                                        "[\"b\", \"b\"]",
                                                        "[\"c\", \"c\"]",
                                                        "[\"d\", \"d\"]"
                                                ]
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                },
                "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
        },
        "serverInfo" : {
                "host" : "obfuscated",
                "port" : obfuscated,
                "version" : "3.4.6-1.7",
                "gitVersion" : "obfuscated"
        },
        "ok" : 1
}`

**Count on non-indexed column**

`db.myCollection.explain().count({"entryVals.col2": {$in:["a","b","c","d"]}})
{
        "queryPlanner" : {
                "plannerVersion" : 1,
                "namespace" : "myDb.myCollection",
                "indexFilterSet" : false,
                "parsedQuery" : {
                        "entryVals.col2" : {
                                "$in" : [
                                        "a",
                                        "b",
                                        "c",
                                        "d"
                                ]
                        }
                },
                "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "COUNT",
                        "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
                                "filter" : {
                                        "entryVals.col2" : {
                                                "$in" : [
                                                        "a",
                                                        "b",
                                                        "c",
                                                        "d"
                                                ]
                                        }
                                },
                                "direction" : "forward"
                        }
                },
                "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
        },
        "serverInfo" : {
                "host" : "obfuscated",
                "port" : obfuscated,
                "version" : "3.4.6-1.7",
                "gitVersion" : "obfuscated"
        },
        "ok" : 1
}`

Comment: I would suggest to insert 100 000 records with large diversity of column values, take another set of metrics and compare again.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that

Comment: also add instruction of how you create index

Comment: please post the explain of the two queries, only that will tell you why you get different results

Comment: I've added the explain now